# Parse Randomly 11 Items From JSON and Display IN HTML

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am a newbie.

I have a JSON file that contains names and urls. All i want to do is get randomly selected 11 items from the JSON object and display them in HTML.

I can parse and randomly dump the content of the JSON but i don't know what to do more. I am thinking to use foreach for printing html but i don't know how to get the items from JSON object.

Here is the project in my mind;

```
<div class="custom-top-tags">
<div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div>
<div class="sm-top-tags-keywords">
<ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list">
 <?php foreach($array as $key=>$value){ ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $key[link]; ?>"><?php echo $key[urun]; ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, i don't know how to fill `$key[link]` and `$key[name]` variables by randomly selected 11 items from JSON file.

Here is current code that i have;

```
$json = file_get_contents('./includes/one-cikanlar.json');
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

shuffle($json_data);

echo $json_data;
```

Here is the JSON structure;

```
 {
   "urunler": [
     {
       "urun":"Matkap",
       "link":"makina-grubu?keyword=Matkap"
     },
     {
       "urun":"İş Eldivenleri",
       "link":"eldiven-grubu"      
     },
     {
       "urun":"Mikser & Karıştırıcı",
       "link":"shop?keyword=Karıştırıcı"
       },
     {
       "urun":"Silikon",
       "link":"shop?keyword=Silikon"
       },
     {
       "urun":"Tangitt",
       "link":"shop?keyword=Tangit"
       },
     {
       "urun":"Lokma Takımı",
       "link":"shop?keyword=Lokma+Takımı"
       },
     ...                                              
   ]
 }
```

To summarize, i need to get randomly selected 11 items from `urunler` object within JSON And print these selected items into HTML.

I am waiting for your suggestions and help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think he's showing just a sample of his `JSON` data

Comment: yes i was displaying just a sample of JSOn tehre are at least 33 items in the object. I did not want to wrote all of them here

Comment: @user9741470 I missed the `...` in the json. Should the links be random and unique or only random and can a duplicate exists?

Comment: they must be unique

Comment: `<?php foreach(array_slice($array,0, 11) as $key=>$value){ ?>`

Comment: @splash58 thank you for the anwer but could you send as code so i can learn and understand better what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array with the items is in `$json_data['urunler'];` instead of `$json_data` so you could shuffle that and use for example a for loop to take 11 items.

```
<?php
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
shuffle($json_data['urunler']);
?>
<div class="custom-top-tags">
    <div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div>
    <div class="sm-top-tags-keywords">
        <ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $json_data['urunler'][$i]['link']; ?>"><?php echo $json_data['urunler'][$i]['urun']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/JeGNs)

Comment: I think we can go somewhere from here. But current code does not run.
 This is the output: <div class="sp-module-content"> Öne Çıkanlar: </div>

Comment: @orko I have added a demo. Wat does not run? Do you get an error?

Comment: It just prints the title "Öne Çıkanlar" and there is nothing more. There is no error or anything But this is just the output that i am getting: <div class="sp-module-content"> Öne Çıkanlar: </div>

Comment: What do you see when you run `var_dump($json_data);` or `var_dump($json_data['urunler']);`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add JSON file: $json = file_get_contents('./includes/one-cikanlar.json'); Now it is working but styling is wrong.

Comment: <div class="sp-module-content"> Öne Çıkanlar: Akü Matkap Ucu İş Eldivenleri Çizme Boya Testere Plastik Boru Makası Yapıştırıcı Kompresör Tank Ölçü Aletleri </div>
It does not print html as it should.

Comment: And one more thing, how we can prevent getting duplicated items?

Comment: Glad it works. For the styling, I have used the html you added to the question. For no duplicate items you might read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php). Try `$json_data['urunler'] = array_unique($json_data['urunler'], SORT_REGULAR);`

Comment: `<div class="custom-top-tags"><div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div><div class="sm-top-tags-keywords"><ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list"> Vidalama Plastik Boru Makası Silikon Matkap Klepe Testere Matkap Ucu Kilit Yapıştırıcı Anahtar Sprey Boya </ul></div></div>`

This is the output but i dould not make this line work
`<li><a href="<?php echo $json_data['urunler'][$i]['link']; ?>"><?php echo $json_data['urunler'][$i]['urun']; ?></a></li>`
It just dumps the name of the product

Comment: The `'<li>` should be inside the `<ul>` and you did not add the for loop to loop the items. Check this demo with unique items and your `<li>` in a loop. https://3v4l.org/HpSCm

Comment: Actually, i was trying this code inside Joomla with sourcerer pluign. The problem was caused by sourcerer algorithm, i have sourcerer's own IDE to paste the code, and it worked. Now i fixed that problem. Thank you so much. I will just have a look the the remove duplicated items. If i could not do it can i ask for your help?

Comment: See my previous comment about the duplicates. It is also in the last demo https://3v4l.org/HpSCm

Comment: you are the man. thanks a lot for helping. It a lot helped me as a newbie to understand and improve my way of thinking.